# Transition animation bug

Tags: javascript, css, animation

If i use in showAnimateWin property offsetHeight, animation work. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p2wozc8a/3/)

```
function end( ) {

    var  top = ( window.innerHeight - win.clientHeight ) / 2,
        left = ( window.innerWidth - win.clientWidth ) / 2;

    win.style.top = top + "px";
    win.style.left = left + "px";
}

function showAnimateWin( ) {
        win.offsetHeight ;//here

        win.classList.add("modal-window-animate");
        end();
 };
```

If i removed win.offsetHeight, animation work only one times. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p2wozc8a/5/)

```
function showAnimateWin( ) { 
        win.classList.add("modal-window-animate");
        end();
 };
```

Why won't work without win.offsetHeight  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably because the `win.offsetHeight;` causes the method to wait for a few milliseconds before the transition can start again. If you put `alert(1);` instead of the `win.offsetHeight;` it will still work. You need to wait for the transition to complete before starting another animation.

UPDATE: [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/p2wozc8a/6/)

This should work without having any delays (check fiddle):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
        showAnimateWin();
    }, 25);
```

Comment: A better option is to simply call `end()` before `win.classList.add("modal-window-animate");`

Comment: I used setTimeout(end, 0 ); but don`t worked, why?

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/p2wozc8a/7/

Comment: @cyber_ua unfortunately to be honest I have no idea :)